# ClearCase: change branch type name?

Tags: unix, clearcase

I used `mkbrtype BRANCH_NAME`, checked out a few files, had some check-ins, etc. Now I discovered I had a typo in the branch name, and it looks pretty ugly. Is there a way I can change the branch name and still have all the versions/checkouts under it? I'm the only one using it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can rename a `brtype` with the [`ct rename` command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rename.htm).

```
cleartool rename brtype:oldname@\vob newname
```

But you will need to:

- change the config spec of your view (non-UCM): no side-effect on checked out files
- or change the name of the stream, remove and recreate your view no the new Stream name (UCM). Your checked-out files still have their checked-out status, but you have to save their local modified content first to re-apply that content to the new view.

Answer (score 6):

Following command may be useful

```
$ cleartool rename brtype:OLD brtype:NEW
```

Answer (score 4):

The methods listed previously probably work, but I just wanted to show the way I did it.

Usage:

```
cleartool chtype -nc new_branch "filepath@@old_branch"
```

Example:

```
cleartool chtype -c "Better name" maintenance "main.c@@\main\branch"
```

Note: -nc is no comment