# Can't find default stream when rebasing development stream

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

When I go to rebase my development stream with the latest baseline, the current integration stream does not automatically show up.  Instead I get a list of all the available streams.  When I select the integration stream from the list, I get the following error:

> Because this stream has no default stream from which to retrieve
>   recommended baselines, the baseline list has been seeded with
>   the stream's current foundation baselines.
>
> To proceed, you'll need to edit the baseline list directly.
>   (Click 'Advanced' to view/edit the baseline list.)

When I go to Project Explorer, and look at recommended baselines, everything shows up correctly.

This had been working correctly historically.  What can I do to set the default stream back to the integration stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't saw that error message before, but a *workaround* would be to:

- [rename the current child stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4733842/6309) (which no longer has the right default parent),
- make an new child stream from the integration stream, and rebasing it with the right baseline from its default parent (the integration stream),
- make the first child stream (the one with the issue) obsolete,
- go on from there.

Answer (score 1):

I can't offer much by way of explanation, but something did magically fix it.

Normally I rebase by right clicking on the development stream and selecting "Rebase Stream...".  This was not working.  However, Going to Toolbox > UCM > Rebase Stream seemed to kick it into gear.

#### Not Working

[image: not working]

#### Working

[image: working]

Hopefully that fixes it for some other person.  If not, you can go with VonC's answer.